# POCO Support in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, poco

While the application I am developing at the moment is written in .net 4.0 against the beta, I have largely been ignoring POCO support in the Entity Framework because I didn't need it. I'm starting to realize, however, that POCO support would be useful in my project. However, Google searches on POCO in the EF yield a lot of results about it "coming in the future" and "sneak peeks."

With the .net 4.0 framework in a Go Live license now, I know that POCO support must be largely implemented. Can anyone point me to a good resource for getting my feet wet on how it all works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julie Lerman has several blog entries on EF 4 POCO.

http://www.google.com/search?q=julie+lerman+poco

Answer (score 2):

Another source for information (besides Julie Lerman's blog) is the ADO.NET team's blog, e.g:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/tags/Entity+Framework/default.aspx